# Ubuntu bridge: not finding installation package

Tags: networking, ubuntu, apt, bridge

I'm following this tutorial to set up a bridge on my ubuntu virtual machine (on virtualbox) so that the vm will register on my home network.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge

But I'm stuck at line 1. It stays at 0%, then tells me it can't connect to that url.

`sudo apt-get update`

Is this an outdated tutorial? I'm using the latest Ubuntu on virtualbox.

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using? Also could you add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 1):

The article you are using to bridge connections is working and not old. The only problem is that it assumes your PC is not connected to the Internet but it tries to download bridge-utils package from Internet.

You can solve this problem by typing the following code in another PC running the same OS version with the same architecture (maybe the OS behind the VM in your case)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bridge-utils
```

...and then copying the '/var/cache/apt/archives' contents of that machine to the same address of the machine (VM) you are trying to bridge connections on.

Comment: The problem is that the host OS is different from the VM OS. Any other ways to get the VM connected to the network?